# How to delete UIImageView from UIScrollView in iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uiscrollview, uiimage

Am created multiple scrollview for gallery. I need to delete image from scrolview and reload it by removing deleted image.

my code:

```
int newscrollviewY = 40;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        UIScrollView *newscrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, newscrollviewY, 320, 100)];
        newscrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        newscrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
        newscrollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        newscrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        int imgx = 3;
        for(int img=0; img<[images count]; img++)
        {

        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgx,0,100,100)];
                imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        imageView1.image = [images objectAtIndex:img];
            imageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [newscrollview addSubview:imageView1];
            imgx = imgx +105;
        }

        [newscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(106 * [images count], 100)];
}
```

Comment: use the method removefromsuperview

Comment: thats ok i got it.. i need to delete like iPhone delete animation

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your `images` array changes, you can first remove all the image views added on your scrollview. Then repeated this same code to add new images.

Or,

You can access the subviews(image views) and change the `image` property to show new image.

BTW, in your code you are creating the scrollview locally, I'd suggest you to maintain the scrollview instance as an ivar, else ensure to remove the scrollview as well before calling this code again.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all scroll content with this,

```
for (UIScrollView *i in yourScrollView.subviews){
    [i removeFromSuperview];
}
```

or you may use delete `removeFromSuperView`method as iDav said.

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for sample like this ???

[image]

Try this code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLongPressed)];
        [subScrollView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Comment: here you not asking question

Comment: wrong answer. please understand question clearly what is questioner expected